# Getting the value out of a textblock

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have these textboxes that hold information that comes from a webservice. I have a class that gathers the information and then when I want to see it, it works fine. Theres a piece of information I want to gather out of the Textblock that has a binding with desc but since my textbox techincally doesnt exist unless the user clicks a button, I can't call the Textbox to gather it's information. Is there any way to do so?

Heres the code I have

```
<ListView x:Name ="View" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding location}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock 
                        x:Name="desc_text" 
                        Text="{Binding desc}"></TextBlock>
                    <Button 
                        x:Name ="website" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                        Content="&#xE109;" 
                        Click="website_Click"></Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My webservice returns some news so the StackPanel Repeats itself sometimes, each with different information (which is what I want) in case it's necessary

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're "gathering information out of a textblock". It looks to me like you're binding the text properties to an instance of some kind of model or viewmodel class. Why not just go to that instance? You're going very far out of your way to make a simple, easy task extremely painful and difficult. You don't store information in the UI, you store it in your model. You just display it in the UI.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Answering to your comment, I'm new to c# and data-binding and I am trying it out. Being honest I just didn't think about, or maybe I'm not sure how it will work. My main objective from all of this is when I click that button named "website" I can get the link in the desc and just redirect it to the link, if that makes sense. From what I thought about, I can't go and gather it from the instance because Visual Studio doesn't find it, because technically it doesn't exist unless I make it appear first, which only happens when the user presses a button

Comment: Where are these controls coming from? Can you show us exactly what you're getting back from the web service? We can walk through doing this MVVM style, and you'll get a basic grounding in how to use XAML without torturing yourself. It's very easy to get it to do most of the work for you.

Answer (score -1):

There might be other ways to do this, but the easiest way imo: Your dynamic textblock has to be binded dynamically in code behind, you can do that right after you create it. Something like this:

```
Binding b = new Binding("color1"); // color1 is the property you are binding to
                b.Source = bindedobjectthat-has-a-color1property-to-bind-to;
                b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                item.SetBinding(Label.BackgroundProperty, b); // Label.BackgroundProperty is the property receiver of this binding
```

You will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Can you explain what advantage there might be in creating the Binding in codebehind?

Comment: He is creating the textblock dynamically, I dont see how you could bind in XAML to an object that is not there in design time. An easy way out could be to create the object in the xaml but with visibility hidden, and then show it after clicking that button he mentions. This way he can set the binding in XAML, but this might not be what he wants.

Comment: Creating the textblock dynamically would be a very bad idea, if that's what he's doing. Do you know what a DataTemplate is?

Comment: Why so hostile? calm down, Marta.  He said the textblock doesnt exist unless the user clicked a button, hence I assumed it was being created in code-behind. Checking again this might not be the case, OP wording confused me, I'm sorry, just trying to help.